# Slow fetch of 1000 rows by primary key

Tags: postgresql

I'm doing performance measurements of PostgreSQL 15 with a large table of 2 billion rows and feel that queries fetching multiple rows from this table are significantly slower than I expected. The table takes up 1 TB on a fast SAN and doesn't fit in memory. The rows have primary keys (bigint) from 1 to 2 billion and were bulk loaded in that order.

When I run a select statement to fetch the bigint primary key and another integer column, with a where clause containing 1000 random keys, the statement takes about 5 seconds to execute.

`select id,otherInt from myTable where id in (list of 1000 random ids);`

The query plan confirms that the primary key index is used. If I run the exact same statement again, when all the pages are in memory, it only takes milliseconds to execute. I assume the 5 seconds are spent reading from disk, but I don't think I'm maxing out my storage, because if I execute multiple similar statements at the same time (with different keys) then they take roughly the same time to finish.

Can it be that Postgres isn't reading the rows from disk in parallel, so the query time is the latency of fetching 1 page multiplied by a few thousand pages? Is there any way to make such a query faster, assuming my storage can keep up?

My real workload isn't going to be fetching rows by their primary key, which could be parallelised manually, this is just a simplified example to eliminate delays from joins and other indexes. I'm thinking that queries that have to return 1000 rows scattered across the table will usually be slower than a simple select on the primary key.

Update:

Explain output:

```
Index Scan using mytable_pkey on public.mytable  (cost=0.58..4661.00 rows=1000 width=10) (actual time=11.212..4433.990 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Output: id, tenant_id
  Index Cond: (mytable.id = ANY ('{list,of,1000,keys}'::bigint[]))
  Buffers: shared hit=2924 read=2076
Settings: effective_cache_size = '150GB', search_path = 'public, public, "$user"', work_mem = '40MB'
Planning Time: 1.522 ms
Execution Time: 4435.692 ms
```

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.mytable (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    tenant_id int2 NOT NULL,
    content_type int4 NOT NULL,
    source_id uuid NOT NULL,
    content_date timestamptz NOT NULL,
    properties jsonb NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Index DDL:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mytable_pkey ON public.mytable USING btree (id);
```

Comment: Did you `ANALYZE` the table after the bulk load?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, yes, but it didn't improve the query speed.

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze,  verbose, buffers, settings)` for this statement, the DDL for the table and the DDL for the indexes involved? All in plain text, as an update to your question.

Comment: Turn on track_io_timing, then look at the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query.

Comment: DDL and explain output added. I'll try to turn on track_io_timing.

Comment: With track_io_timing enabled EXPLAIN seems to show most of the time is spent on I/O:

I/O Timings: shared/local read=3742.855

Execution Time: 3859.542 ms

Comment: I would drop the index mytable_pkey, since id is already the primary key and an index has been created in the background. Back to the problem, your SAN seems to be pretty slow. Not much the database can do about this. Your configuration isn't optimized for performance either, but that wouldn't make the SAN any faster. Did you run pg_bench on this SAN? If so, could you share the settings for pg_bench and it's results?

Comment: I'd say that you need a faster disk.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I've run a pgbench test with scaling factor 1000 and 200 clients with 10000 transactions each. That gives me 11810 TPS (without initial connection time) and average latency of 17 ms. Database initialisation took 140 seconds. That's okay, isn't it?

Comment: To me it looks like your scale factor is too small, you need 20,000 to get big integers and the number of records comparable to your own test. I would also run pgbench for 30 to 60 minutes, not just a small number of transactions. Your current results could be the result from RAM, not disk.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, now I've tried a pgbench test with scaling factor 60,000 (db size ~800 GB, with 256 GB RAM). Running 200 clients with 150,000 transactions each, the result is 9734 TPS and an average latency of 19 ms. The test ran for 51 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL has limited ways to do concurrent IO.  If you are doing a bitmap scan, then it will issue up to effective_io_concurrency IO requests asynchronously, so you should increase that setting.  However, the planner will not choose to do a bitmap scan just in order to take advantage of high effective_io_concurrency, it has to already be doing the bitmap scan anyway.  In your case it doesn't seem to want to do that, so you could try to force it by `set enable_indexscan=off`.  This need to twist the planner's arm makes it unappealing, but in your specific case it is also limited because the index consultation is always done sequentially.  Since you are consulting 1000 random index leaf pages, that is a lot of IO it would still need to do sequentially.  If you were instead finding 1000 random table rows which all had the same source_id (for example), that would be much more efficient as it would only need to consult a few dozen mostly-adjacent index pages sequentially before starting in on the 1000 random table pages.

Another way to get IO concurrency is through query parallelization, but your particular query is not eligible for that just because it is not implemented for IN lists.  This is where your assumption that this query is a good model for more complex queries falls down.  A more complex query might be easier to get parallelization for than a simple one.  You would need to show us a realistic query.  (Parallel query is primarily for CPU parallelization, but can also be used to get IO parallelization.)

The most classic way to get concurrency would be to just have many sessions each of which independently do what they want to do and the kernel can schedule all of their IO to run asynchronously and concurrently from the storage system's perspective even though it it is synchronous from the perspective of any one session.  Of course if you don't naturally have many sessions with independent tasks list, this can be hard to arrange for.

Finally in this specific case, you had an index on `(id, otherInt)` or on `(id) include (otherInt)` then you could get an index-only scan.  The IO would still be synchronous, but there would only have half as much as it as you only need to visit the index and not the table (assuming it is well vacuumed).  This would be hard to generalize to other queries, and you might fall into the trap of trying to build on specialized index for each different query.  Also, for a very UPDATE-heavy table it can be hard or impossible for the vacuuming to keep up with the need to set visibility map bits.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is very interesting. I see your point about having to read a lot of index pages. What I'm actually doing is using a joined secondary table with indexed key/value pairs used for locating relevant records in the main table. After using the efficient index in the secondary table, the main table primary key index is used to fetch the actual data, causing many page reads for index and data in the main table. I'll try some other designs and see if I can get the key/value pairs in the main table in an efficient way